# Switch debian install from legacy to UEFI

Tags: boot-loader, uefi

I have Debian 7 installed on my laptop on the ssd and windows 8 on the hdd. Currently to boot Windows I go into the bios and change a boot setting from legacy to UEFI, which means to boot Debian I am using the legacy option. When I originally installed Debian I recall it being a pain to work with UEFI so that is why I did it this way.

My question is, now that I have more time, is it possible to switch the Debian install so that it can dual boot with windows under UEFI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this by uninstalling Grub and installing rEFInd. This was a very painstaking procedure and many times I had to use Super Grub Disk to boot back into Linux. But it does work now.

I followed the procedure at http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to have both os's as the same, either UEFI or MBR/Legacy.  You cannot have Linux legacy and 8 uefi.

Comment: For a while I did have both UEFI Windows 8 and MBR Debian 7. The way I switched between them was by changing my settings in BIOS from UEFI to MBR and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

A short step by step howto can be found here:

[Switch Debian 7 wheezy from legacy to UEFI boot mode](https://getreu.net/public/downloads/Transform-Debian_7_wheezy-from_legacy_to_UEFI_boot_mode.html)

Comment: Please provide the details here, and use links for pointers to non-relevant details and/or backup information. Currently if the link goes dead your answer loses any of its value it might have.

Comment: Provide your answer here not the link.

Comment: It's just a link but it's a good one.